# Is there a theme equivalent of hook_install()?

Tags: 8

I want my theme to control certain block settings, like which elements of the system branding block are enabled. To me it makes sense for that to be code in the theme, not a module, because at the moment the only way I've found to access the config programmatically involves using the theme name.

```
/** @var Drupal\Core\Config\Config $config */
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('block.block.my_theme_branding');
$config->set('settings.use_site_logo', false);
$config->save();
```

Since this is a one off config change, I think it should only happen when the theme is installed/activated. It there a theme function/hook that behaves like `hook_install` does for modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may provide [configuration](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/config_api/8) via YAML files as part of a module, profile or theme install by adding them to the `config/install` directory inside the respective project. So, for example, a file `block.block.my_theme_branding.yml` would install the branding block into the specified region. This would then contain the setting to disable the site slogan by default. Take a look at [block.block.bartik_branding.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!profiles!standard!config!install!block.block.bartik_branding.yml/8) in the standard profile as a starting point.

If the specific block is provided by another module, then it should probably be placed in the `config/optional` directory.

Answer (score 0):

That was a missing feature; however, after a conversation in IRC that is a feature that we want to implemented. Its currently been working at [Add (back) hook_install for themes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2652542).

The solution from @mradcliffe have a lot limitation, because you cant override a anything unless you are a profile.